# Gmail trigger when mail sent

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I am making script by GAS or Gmail add-on in the enviroment.
I need run script after Gmail sent mail and get status of it (To,cc,Title,Body). 
I found managing label in Gmail api , but "sent" can not is include manually applied

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you support! I found https://youtu.be/wjHp9_NAEJo and tried to been described script.